# How to write generic "validate" method to receive various inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I have several functions that have some common inputs:

```
func_1(x1, x2, x3, y1)
func_2(x1, x3, y2)
func_3(x1, x2, x3, y1, y3)
```

I want to write input error handling code for all the inputs (e.g. throw exception if `x1` is `None`). I found the way of configuring input validation function as a good option, where all the inputs from all the functions can be checked/validated

```
def validate_inputs(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3)
    # do the all checks for x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3 here
```

and called from corresponding functions **with necessary inputs**:

```
def func_1(x1, x2, x3, y1)
    validate_inputs(x1, x2, x3, y1)
    # do whatever the function is supposed to do

def func_2(x1, x3, y2)
    validate_inputs(x1, x3, y2)
    # do whatever the function is supposed to do
```

**Question:** How should I configure `validate_inputs` to have "flexible" inputs like this?

Comment: Possible solution using optional arguments ?

Comment: look at *args and **kwargs

Comment: use `validate_inputs` as a `decorator`, looks better..

Comment: Struggling with configuring using **kwargs, does then some of the inputs have to be optional?

Comment: Why don't you just pass a list of arguments `args=[x1, x2]` `func_2(args)` and validate the list? `validate_inputs(args)`. This works just fine if you're going to do the same validation for whatever value you pass. If not, it might involve some more processing

Comment: Got solved the problem nicely with **kwargs and optional inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check it out:

First, write some validators:

```
def validate_int(i):
    if not type(i) == int:
        raise Exception(f"{i} is not a number")

//TODO complete code
def validate_something(i):
    if not ....:
       raise Exception(f"{i} is not something..")
```

Then, hold the validators in some dict:

```
validators = {'x1': validate_int,
              'y1': validate_int,
              'y3': validate_int,
              'x2': validate_something}
```

Write a decorator to validate the args:

```
def validate_args(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            validators.get(k, lambda x: x)(v)
    return wrapper
```

Now, you want each method to be validated to wrapped and be called with key-value vars:

```
@validate_args
def func1(*, x1,y1,y2):
    pass


@validate_args
def func2(*, x2,x5):
    pass
```

That's it. Just call your methods..

```
func1(x1=1,y1=2,y2=3,y3=4)

func2(x1=5, y3={'a':3})
```